# Put a modal form in middle of the form in filament v3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

How can I make 'price' to be recognized as a member of the form?

```
    public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Wizard::make([
                    Wizard\Step::make('First Step')
                        ->schema([
                            TextInput::make('title')->required(),
                             Forms\Components\Actions::make([
                                Action::make('Custom Modal')
                                    ->button()
                                    ->form([
                                        TextInput::make('price')->prefix('$')->required(),
                                    ])
                        ]),
                    Wizard\Step::make('Second Step')
                        ->schema([
                                //...
                        ]),
                ]),
            ]);
    }
```

when I submit the form it passes this error:

**SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'price' cannot be null.**

Generally it doesn't work for every column that I put in modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing a lot of ways, Now this is the answer:

```php
//....
Wizard\Step::make('First Step')
    ->schema([
        TextInput::make('title')->required(),
        Hidden::make('price'),
        Forms\Components\Actions::make([
            Action::make('Custom Modal')
                ->button()
                ->form([
                    TextInput::make('price')->prefix('$')->required()
                    ->default(
                        function (MyModel $record = null) {
                            return  $record?->price;
                        }
                    ),
                ])
                ->action(function (Set $set, array $data) {
                    $set('price', $data['price']);
                }),
        ]),

    ]),
//....
```

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to discover the problem. You can try my code out, 100 percent I'm sure.

```php
//....
Wizard\Step::make('First Step')
    ->schema([
        TextInput::make('title')->required(),
        Hidden::make('price'),
        Forms\Components\Actions::make([
            Action::make('Custom Modal')
                ->button()
                ->form([
                    TextInput::make('price')->prefix('$')->required()
                    ->default(
                        function (MyModel $record = null) {
                            return  $record?->price;
                        }
                    ),
                ])
                ->action(function (Set $set, array $data) {
                    $set('price', $data['price']);
                }),
        ]),

    ]),
//....
```